# Improve this code: How to avoid using "any" when spying on module with Jest? And how to avoid generic?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript-generics

I've written a snippet of code that returns a module with all its exported members as jest spied on functions:

```
export const spyOnModule = <T>(mod: any) => {
  const obj = {} as {
    [x in keyof T]: jest.SpyInstance<any, any>
  }
  const modKeys = Object.keys(mod)
  modKeys.forEach((x) => {
    const key = x as keyof T
    const currentProp = mod[key]
    if (typeof currentProp === 'function') {
      obj[key] = jest.spyOn(mod, key as string)
    }
  })
  return obj
}
```

This is how it would be used in a test:

```
// MyComponent.test.ts
import * as LookupApi from 'Data/LookUp/LookupApi2'
import { spyOnModule } from 'helper'
const mockLookupApi = spyOnModule<typeof LookupApi>(LookupApi)

// mockLookupApi would have all the methods as spied functions

// {
//     readonly useGetLookupsQuery: jest.SpyInstance<any, any>;
//     readonly lookupApiReducer: jest.SpyInstance<any, any>;
//     readonly lookupApiReducerPath: jest.SpyInstance<any, any>;
//     readonly lookupApiMiddleware: jest.SpyInstance<...>;
//     readonly lookupApiEndpoints: jest.SpyInstance<...>;
// }

describe('MyComponent',()=>{
  it('Should call the api',()=>{
    mockLookupApi.useGetLookupsQuery.mockReturnValue('abc')

    // MyComponent act

    expect(mockLookupApi.lookupApiReducerPath).toBeCalled()
    expect(mockLookupApi.useGetLookupsQuery).toBeCalledWith(123)
  })
})
```

Very handy, but there are 3 things I don't like about it:

1. When calling spyOnModule I have to use `<typeof ...>` to get the module method names in the return object. I'd love to be able to just infer the type from the module and NOT have to pass a generic.
2. mod is the `any` type. Not a big fan of that. Is there a type for modules?
3. I'd love the spied functions to retain their parameter and return values. Right now I just returns `<any, any>` for all of them because I'm not sure how to get the parameter and return value type.

Can these issues be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, just don't specify `(mod: any)` otherwise you're over-writing the type with any. Instead use a generic parameter and TS will infer it -i.e `(mod: T)`
2. Modules are just objects, so we can constrain T as being an object, like so: `<T extends object>`
3. Yes, you have to map over values and then use conditional types to figure out which are functions, extract the arguments and return types (denoted below with `A` and `R` respectively) and which should be left as-is.

Side note - your current implementation will remove exported non-function values, is that intentional?

Sticking those all together, this should work:

```js
type WithModuleSpies<T extends object> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R
    ? jest.SpyInstance<R, A>
    : T[key];
};

type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? K : never;
}[keyof T] &
  string;

export const spyOnModule = <T extends object>(mod: T): WithModuleSpies<T> => {
  const spies = { ...mod } as WithModuleSpies<T>;

  for (const key in mod) {
    const value = mod[key];

    if (typeof value === "function") {
      spies[key] = jest.spyOn(
        mod,
        (key as unknown) as FunctionPropertyNames<T>
      );
    }
  }

  return spies;
};

const spied = spyOnModule(MyModule);

const call = spied.foo.mock.calls[0]; // [a: number, b: number] 
const instance = spied.foo.mockImplementation((a, b) => 3); // impl has type (a: number, b: number) => number | (a: number, b: number) => undefined
const value = spied.MY_CONST; // string
```

Comment: I get this error: `Type 'Required<T>[FunctionPropertyNames<T>] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? SpyInstance<ReturnType<Required<T>[FunctionPropertyNames<T>]>, ArgsType<...>> : never' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? SpyInstance<R, A> : T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.
  Type 'SpyInstance<ReturnType<Required<T>[FunctionPropertyNames<T>]>, ArgsType<Required<T>[FunctionPropertyNames<T>]>>' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? SpyInstance<R, A> : T[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.`